# Разбить строку по регистру?

Tags: jquery, строки

Приветствую! Работаю с библиотекой анимаций. Добавляю, удаляю классы с помощью JQuery и в нужный момент анимация работает. Суть в том что когда я добавляю анимацию, допустим `fadeInLeft` мне нужно удалить (если есть) `fadeInRight`. Очевидно, что начало одинаковое `fadeIn` концовки разные. И пришла идея просто разбивать строку по регистру и менять последний элемент получившегося массива. Не уверен, но может все же есть способ разбить строку на массив именно по регистру, а не разделителю?

Comment: `'fadeInLeft'.split(/(?=[A-Z])/); // ['fade', 'In', 'Left']`.

Comment: Не надо так делать. Передавайте в конструктор анимации оба класса: и in, и out...

Comment: Возможно немного не то что вы хотели, но можно использовать replace("fadeIn","") уберет в строке все и оставит только Left. А вообще лучше добавить данные пита data-direction="left" и получать его.